# For Bing Maps or Google Maps or ArcGIS - Solar Teminator (Sun Footprint) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, bing-maps, dst

I am looking for a way to represent on a map the Solar Terminator or Sun FootPrint. In which ever map you want or on one you know to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example here: http://www.fourmilab.ch/cgi-bin/Earth/action?opt=-p

For which the sourcecode can be downloaded from: http://www.fourmilab.ch/earthview/source/

Note that this is written in C, not C#, but it's the closest I could find.